# Why do I need click two times to get result from a callback function

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile- 1.4.2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">
 <script type='text/javascript'  src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'  src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
        //$.support.cors =true,
        //$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

        $('#frmLogin').validate({
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                username: {
                    required: "Please enter your username."
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please enter your password."
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                //alert('there doesn't exist a valid url as yet');
                $("#frmLogin").submit(function (event) {
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    var credentials = { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val() };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "api/auth", // this url is just a placeholder
                        cache: false,
                        data: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function(data,status,jqxhr)
                        {
                            //validate the response here, set variables... whatever needed
                            //and if credentials are valid, forward to the next page
                            if (data.status == "success")
                            {
                                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                                localStorage.setItem("acccessToken", obj.accessToken);
                                alert(obj.accessToken);
                                //authUsername = $("#username").val();
                                //var encrytPswd = mm.crypt.encrypt('sha1', $("#password").val());
                                //localStorage.setItem(authUsername, encrytPswd);
                                //localStorage.setItem('authUsername', authUsername);
                                //localStorage.setItem('authPassword', encrytPswd);
                                //mm.page.show('configuration', {});
                                //$.mobile.changePage($("#main_page"));
                                //window.location.href = "http://www.jqueryvalidation.org";
                            }
                            else if(data.status== "error")
                            {
                                alert("Authentication Invalid.Please try again!");
                                return false;
                            }
                            //or show an error message
                        },
                        error: function (jqxhr, status, errorMsg)
                        {
                            // server couldn't be reached or other error 
                            alert("jqXHR Status : " + jqxhr.status + " Status: " + status + " Error: " + errorMsg);
                        }
                    }, "json");
                    return false;
                });
                //$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#success', {
                //    reload: false
                //});
            }

        });
    });

    </script>
  <style type="text/css">
label.error {
color: red;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.4;
margin-top: 0.5em;
width: 100%;
float: none;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
label.error { margin-left: 0; display: block; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
label.error { display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; }
}
em { color: red; font-weight: bold; padding-right: .25em; }
</style>
</head>
<body id="loginBody">
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header">
         </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a id="main_page" href="www.google.com"></a>
            <form id="frmLogin" method="post" action="api/auth" data-ajax="false">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">
                        <em>* </em> Username:
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="username"
                           name="username" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="password">
                        <em>* </em>Password:
                    </label>
                    <input type="password" id="password"
                           name="password" />
                </div>

                <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <button class="btnLogin" type="submit" id="loginBtn"
                            data-theme="a">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="success" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header">
             <h1>Thank You!!!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I click button to fire `submit` event on the form and given the fact that the url that I'm posting my request to doesn't exist so it should execute the following function:

```
error: function (jqxhr, status, errorMsg)
{
    // server couldn't be reached or other error 
    alert("jqXHR Status : " + jqxhr.status + " Status: " + status + "  Error: " + errorMsg);
}
```

which it does but I have to click the button two times, why not after a single click the above function is executed?

Comment: You add `submit` event handler on each "submit" inside `submitHandler` handler. Instead of handling submit event inside validation submit handler, you add custom submit event handler - it's not a good idea. Just remove `$("#frmLogin").submit(function (event) {` and related `});` lines.

Comment: @Regent, thanks for your reply, so if I'm following you right. Do you mean that I should remove $("#frmLogin").submit(function (event) { and related }); from inside of .validate() and write another event handler and just call that event handler where I'm firing the submit event.

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/zebstp0n/) to see what I mean.

Comment: ok I got you and removed $("#frmLogin").submit(function (event) { and related }); and let the remaining code as such, it works fine now.

Comment: That is what it was about :)

Comment: After correcting the code still I can't understand one thing that when I try to validate my empty username/password text boxes then why only validate event goes till checking the rules and displaying messages to the client if both the boxes or any of them is empty, why doesn't it go to make an Ajax call in the first place along with empty box validation. Precisely what I mean is that if boxes/box are/is empty the event stops there if they are not then the event propagate to Ajax function, why doesn't it propagate all the way to Ajax function no matter whether textboxes are empty or not.

Comment: It is the whole idea of validation: do not permit form submit until all fields are filled correctly.

Comment: Now another problem I'm facing is that I put a normalize.css file in the root folder named CSS though I have commented it out in the above code. But no matter what I do this .css file is not all implementing the effects/layout/appearance for html code. I'm doing all this using multiple device hybrid apps in Visual Studio 2013.I tried referencing .css file giving both the absolute and the relative path but to no avail.